# How to make an overlapped image clickable in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, onclick

I have a image of a map and i want to plot some points/markers on the map. These markers must be clickable. I have used a custom view class to plot the markers at my required points.The markers are getting plotted but the problem is that either the marker is not clickable or when i set onClick listener on the custom view,the whole image receives the click event(whereever i click on image, onClick is called,but i want  only click on the marker to initiate onClick). Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create your custom MapOverlay and inside put the code the function. In this code above,  Override the OnTap method.

```
  public class MapOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay {

private ArrayList<OverlayItem> mOverlays = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
private Context mContext;

public MapOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker,Context context) {
    super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
    mContext = context;
}

@Override
protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return mOverlays.get(i);
}

public void addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay) {
    mOverlays.add(overlay);
    populate();
}

public void clearOverlay() {
    mOverlays.clear();
    populate();
}
@Override
public int size() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return mOverlays.size();
}



@Override
protected boolean onTap(int index) {
  OverlayItem item = mOverlays.get(index);
  AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
  dialog.setTitle(item.getTitle());
  dialog.setMessage(item.getSnippet());
  dialog.show();
  return true;
}
```

}

Comment: Great. Will try it out and let you know @FMMobile Felipe Meneze.

Comment: ItemizedOverlay  is only used to add overlay items on a MapView. But i am not using the MapView and all i have is just an image. I want to draw some more small images on it and make those small images clickable.

Comment: Felipe Meneze I tried to use above but coudn't becoz i am not using the map api. I am actually kind of  simulating maps by having having a static map image and drawing markers at my required coordinates, and i am successful in doing so, by extending View class nad overriding onDraw method. But now the problem is that the markers are not clickable. A touch anywhere on the map is calling the onTouch method.

Comment: If are using onDraw method inside the View with Canvas , you'll need to do some calculations to find out where the user is touching, and get the coords to compare if is in your overlay coord. This is the way that we use in games. Override main onTouch Activity , get the coords using ACTION_DOWN, and then compare with the position of your overlay method.